# Adverbs of manner - position

Tags: adverb-placement

I have a problem with identifying the positon of adverbs of manner in sentences. I don't know why they are placed like this.

Let me have a look at the examples:

> She **carefully** looked at her reflection in the mirror for ten minutes.

Why is "carefully" placed before the verb?

> He looked **nervously** out of the window to see if anyone was there.

Why is "nervously" placed after the verb?

Answer (score 2):

If the verb is intransitive (ie there is no object), an adverb of manner is usually placed after the main verb. In literature or poetry it can also be placed before the verb at the start of the main clause.

> The crowd cheered **loudly** as the band passed by. - *correct*
>   The crowd **loudly** cheered as the band passed by. - *literary*
>   **Loudly** the crowd cheered as the band passed by. - *literary*

If the verb only has an indirect object (ie there is a preposition between verb and noun, the adverb normally goes after the main verb, though it can also go at the end of the sentence: this is common when using a long adverbal phrase.

> She stared **intently** at the mirror - *correct*
>   She stared at the mirror **with great deliberation** - *acceptable if it's a long adverb phrase*
>   she **intently** stared at the mirror - *literary*
>   **Intently**, she stared at the mirror - *literary*

When a verb has a direct object, you never put an adverb of manner between the verb and its direct object: instead, you put it at end of the clause, or before the verb.

> The children ate **greedily** the cake as soon as it was placed on the table. - *incorrect*
>   The children ate the cake **greedily** as soon as it was placed on the table. - *correct*
>   The children **greedily** ate the cake as soon as it was placed on the table. - *correct*
>   **Greedily**, the children ate the cake as soon as it was placed on the table. - *literary*

Looking at your two sentences, **carefully** is placed before the verb for literary effect, and **nervously** is placed after the verb because this the is normal position for a verb with an indirect object (the window).

Answer (score 0):

Adverbs of manner, place and time usually go in end position,
often in that order. Adverbs of manner say how something happens or is done.
Examples: ***angrily, happily, fast, slowly, well, badly, nicely,
noisily, quietly, hard, softly.***

*He drove off angrily. She read the letter slowly.
You speak English well. John works really hard.*

**Adverbs in -ly** can also go in **mid-position** if the adverb is
not the main focus of the message.

*She angrily tore up the letter. I slowly began to feel better*
again.

M.Swan *PEU*

Comment: So why is "carefully" before the verb, not after the verb in my sentence?

Comment: You can use it either in mid- or end-position— _She looked carefully  at her reflection in the mirror for ten minutes._ is also correct .

Comment: What about these examples?:
She read the letter slowly.
She slowly read the letter.
She read slowly the letter.
Are all these sentences correct?

Comment: Yes. What is changing here is the focus of the sentence—usually the most important part is shifted to the end.