# Where the adverb of manner could be placed in this sentence

Tags: adverbs, adverb-placement

I'm looking for information about the position of adverbs of manner in a sentence. I looked up several pages related to adverb placements [here](https://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/flatmates/episode75/languagepoint.shtml), [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/140221/adverbs-of-manner-position), [here](https://7esl.com/adverb-placement/) and [here](https://www.grammar-quizzes.com/adv_manner2.html).

As I understood, adverbs of manner normally go at the end of a sentence/clause, or they could be placed at mid-position in a sentence. So, if the sentence has an auxiliary verb within then the adverb could be placed:

- *Mid position*: The adverb is placed between the auxiliary verb and the main verb.
- *End position*: The adverb is placed at the end of the clause/sentence.

Thus, are the following two sentences correct? if the two sentences are correct, then do they both have the same meaning?

1. Recently, people were withdrawing their money **gradually** from their bank accounts to transfer it to an external country.
2. Recently, people were **gradually** withdrawing their money from their bank accounts to transfer it to an external country.

Comment: Hi, welcome to ELL! +1 for the details and cited sources.

Comment: @EddieKal thank you. I hope my question could be answered

Comment: To me, the first suggests that people were withdrawing money a little at a time, the second that the number of people who did so was gradually increasing. (This is only my interpretation, not any kind of rule.)

Comment: ...and both versions could be seen as ambiguous. To express my second meaning, you could say "Gradually, more and more people were withdrawing..."

Comment: @KateBunting Interesting. So, in the way that the two sentences are written, it is not clear what the adverb is modifying, although the position of the adverb could suggest that it is modifying the "withdraw" verb and not the number of people?

Comment: The second is more ambiguous than the first.

Comment: @KateBunting For me, they are exactly the same thing. gradually modifies withdrawing regardless of where it's placed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They both have the same meaning, although the second sentence sounds more natural.

Based on the position of **gradually**, you might say that the first sentence emphasizes the withdrawal (gradual withdrawals) and the second sentence emphasizes the people (people gradually withdrawing), but that would be very subtle if it's true.